# How to use Orderby Clause with IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written following code:

```
IEnumerable<Models.bookings> search = new List<bookings>();
search = new available_slotsRepositories().GetAvailableSlot(param1,param2);       
var data = from s in search.AsEnumerable().
           OrderByDescending(c => c.BookingDate)
           select s;
```

i have also tried this and it does not work:

```
search.OrderByDescending(c => c.BookingDate);
```

Third line gives me following error:
**Expression cannot contain lambda expressions**

Any one guide me how can i fix this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to look at it in the Inspector window? (Also your `new List<bookings>()` is pointless, it's immediately overwritten.)

Comment: The following works fine for me (in LINQPad against Northwind) `from c in Customers.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(c => c.CompanyName) select c`. This leads me to question what is the data source and what does GetAvailableSlot return? Also, how are you consuming this to know if something else is jumping on this and overriding your ordering.

Comment: What does you GetAvailableSlot return? If it's not a list of entities then of course you can't make enumerable out of it...

Comment: It returns IEnumerable<Models.bookings>

Answer (score 0):

why r u using new List()??

follow the below pattern

```
IEnumerable<Step> steps = allsteps.Where(step => step.X <= Y);

steps = steps.OrderBy(step => step.X);
```

NOTE:

IEnumerable makes no guarantees about ordering, but the implementations that use IEnumerable may or may not guarantee ordering.

For instance, if you enumerate List, order is guaranteed, but if you enumerate HashSet no such guarantee is provided, yet both will be enumerated using the IEnumerable interface

Perhaps you are looking for the IOrderedEnumerable interface? It is returned by extensions methods like OrderBy() and allow for subsequent sorting with ThenBy().

Comment: Hi Neel, thanks for the answer yes your information is useful for me, let me try to implement in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var data = (from s in search
       OrderByDescending(c => c.BookingDate)
       select s).ToList();
```

That will make a List which is IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need "new" if as you say GetAvailableSlot returns an IEnumerable. What I think your code should look like assuming GetAvailableSlot returns IEnumerable is this:

```
var data = available_slotsRepositories().GetAvailableSlot(param1,param2).ToList().OrderByDescending(c => c.BookingDate);
```

All you're doing to your recordset is ordering the results there is no need to have multiple variables declared. If this still doesn't work then we need to see more of the code in order to see what the problem is...